# WSDL xsd:choice to java?

Tags: java, parsing, xsd, wsdl

I'm parsing a WSDL which has a xsd:choice.
How can I model a xsd:choice on java?, I didn't find a union class or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JAXB**](http://jaxb.java.net/) does this , Give it a try it will choose proper model.

Comment: I'm using EasyWSDL to parse the WSDL.

Comment: @Federico JAXB will create model for you from parser XSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Marker" interface (an interface which defines no methods) and let the different choices be a class which implements that interface.